# Eclipse running previous program?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

After creating on program, I moved on to creating a new on in a new class. When I ran this program though, it ran the previous program. I have read several answers to this question, but changing the run configuration doesn't work either...? Here is my code, does it run in your eclipse?

```
package Userinterfaces;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;

import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

 class Dropdown extends JFrame {

private JComboBox box;
private JLabel picture;

private static String[] filename = {"swag.png", "code.png"};
private Icon[] pics = {new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(filename [0]))};


public Dropdown(){
    super("The title");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());


    box = new JComboBox (filename); //Automatically put the array in a list for us

    box.addItemListener(
            new ItemListener(){ //automatically implements itemlistener
                public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event){
                    if (event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
                        picture.setIcon(pics[box.getSelectedIndex()]);
                }

            }
    );

    add(box);
    picture = new JLabel (pics [0]);
    add(picture);

}
}

public class main {
public static void main (String args){

    Dropdown down = new Dropdown();
    down.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    down.setSize(300,200);
    down.setVisible(true);


}
 }
```

Now when I change the dropdown selection I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at Userinterfaces.Dropdown$1.itemStateChanged(main.java:33)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.fireItemStateChanged(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.selectedItemChanged(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.contentsChanged(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractListModel.fireContentsChanged(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel.setSelectedItem(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedItem(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedIndex(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboPopup$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboPopup$1.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: I completely agree, but I think it is an issue with eclipse. The way it is not working is that it is not running the correct class. It is running the previous project that I was working on, after moving on to a new project, the previous project is still being run, despite multiple efforts to run the **correct** program.

Comment: No, your code does not provide the correct main method for Eclipse (or java.exe) to invoke.

Comment: This is a new problem.  Please open a new question instead of completely changing your existing question.

Answer (score 4):

The main method must be exactly right.  Change args to String[] in your main method definition.  Now Eclipse should allow you to right-click it in the navigator and select run.

(Also, the class should be named Main, not main)

Comment: Do you mean like this? public static void main (String [] args){

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at Userinterfaces.Dropdown.<init>(main.java:19)
 at Userinterfaces.main.main(main.java:49)

Comment: Now your program runs!  :D

Comment: (and it cannot find swag,png in your classpath)

Comment: Thanks! Now the window is showing up, but when I change the drop down menu to code.png I get this giant error:

Comment: @Billybobsteven its an array out of bounds error, and the message tells you where to look. Make the effort to fix it.

Comment: @Billybobsteven for example i can see that `pics`, the array being accessed, has length 1, so anything other than 0 in `box.getSelectedIndex()` will throw

Comment: Why though, I have two indexes: [0] && [1]. So shouldn't it work then? Please explain; thankyou

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: Right click the class you want to run and then choose run.

Option 2: Delete all previous configurations by going to the Run Configurations window and then add a new configuration where you add your file.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to your Eclipse configuration. You probably have it set such that when you click on the green "Run" button it will execute the last program you executed. Try right-clicking on the class name in the Package Explorer and selecting "Run As -> Java Application"

Comment: To do that, I needed to make it String[] args, which I did, but then I got the following error

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source) at Userinterfaces.Dropdown.<init>(main.java:19) at Userinterfaces.main.main(main.java:49) –

Answer (score 0):

try to change,

```
public static void main (String args){
```

to

```
public static void main (String args[]){
```

Answer (score 0):

If u are a java user then try to use this method
--> go to Run
and -->then click on Run configuration and then -->select the java application and  browse your required file and then click on Run
Now it will be fine